# SOLR : Logging Bad Requests

Tags: lucene, solr, slf4j, java.util.logging

I cant seem to figure out how to make Solr log all bad resuests - Basically whenever a bad URL comes in, say, a request on a requesthandler that does not exist like `qt=unknownhandler`, I need to log it.

I can see the Solr startup logs and exception logs in my log file, but NOT the bad requests.

Im logging using JDK4 java.util.Logging and solr uses slf4j and slf4j-jdk internally, My tomcat_dir/conf/logging.properties looks like this:

```
5SOLR.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = ALL
5SOLR.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
5SOLR.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = SOLR.


org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/solr].level = ALL
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/solr].handlers = 5SOLR.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
```

and I have added 5SOLR.org.apache.juli.FileHandler to the set of handlers. Why is it that I **CANNOT** see the Bad requests, while I **CAN** see these kind of logs :

```
Sep 7, 2011 12:49:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
FINE: Sending application start events
Sep 7, 2011 12:49:04 PM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession readObject
FINE: readObject() loading session C8A52B935A03A78BEC4A799119A79B49
Sep 7, 2011 12:49:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
FINE: Starting filters
Sep 7, 2011 12:49:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
FINE:  Starting filter 'SolrRequestFilter'
```

Comment: Solrconfig.xml has no elements concerning logging of HTTP STATUS CODE:400 (Bad Request) events. Thanks in advance to any "answer-ers"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can see all requests send to your server in access log.
just comment out AccessLogValve in $TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server.xml.

```xml
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"  
           prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt" pattern="common" resolveHosts="false"/>
```

There is no way to logging 4xx request, but hack source code as following description.

remove test code condition in **org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.java** **sendError** method.

```java
protected void sendError(HttpServletResponse res, Throwable ex) throws IOException {
  int code=500;
  String trace = "";
  if( ex instanceof SolrException ) {
    code = ((SolrException)ex).code();
  }

  // For any regular code, don't include the stack trace
  if( code == 500 || code < 100 ) {
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    ex.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
    trace = "\n\n"+sw.toString();

    SolrException.logOnce(log,null,ex );

    // non standard codes have undefined results with various servers
    if( code < 100 ) {
      log.warn( "invalid return code: "+code );
      code = 500;
    }
  }
  res.sendError( code, ex.getMessage() + trace );
}
```

after compile, you need put your new apache-solr-core-*.jar to WEB-INF/lib, and restart your web container. you will see all of errors like below.

> Sep 22, 2011 5:29:18 PM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
>   SEVERE: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: unknown handler: notexist
>           at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:227)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:555)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Comment: This will log all the requests, and I did not need to configure anything, this piece of configuration was already there off the shelf.
I need to make SOLR log Bad requests made on it. (As a temporary solution I made the application log the solr bad requests.)

Comment: This is good & works for me! I was keeping the hack & recompile source code as the last option (for sake of smooth updating of solr later). But this helped me to do just that, although I had to change a little more than what you mentioned here.